# How to make array on textviews id

Tags: java, android

So I want do like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Textview[] a = {oldtoday00, oldtoday01, ...};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int I = 0; I < a.length; I++) {
             a[I] = (Textview) findViewById(R.id.a[I]);
        }
    }
```

So that I can declare those textviews looping that array instead to write thousands of rows.

But there is problem with Textview[] a = {oldtoday00, oldtoday01, ...};
It says cannot resolve symbol oldtoday00

Comment: You miss something in the last line. `TextView[] a = new TextView[]
 {findViewById(R.id.oldtoday00), ...};`

Comment: yeah but  I don't want to write all textboxes, I want declare them by looping like this for (int I = 0; I < a.length; I++) {
     a[I] = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.a[I])
}

Comment: If you like my answer, accept (and vote) please... :D

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but those answers didn't help me, of course my question is not clear. I edit that once more.

Answer (score 1):

Resource `id`s are integer identifiers assigned by the system.

You may not know exact values so you cannot directly make use of them.

Instead, you get the parent `View` of your `TextView`s and access its children, which are again `TextView`s that you want to access.

```
ConstraintLayout cl = findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout);
TextView[] oldtoday = new TextView[cl.getChildCount()]
for (int i = 0; i < oldday.length; i++) {
    oldtoday[i] = (TextView) cl.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? It is just a simple array declaration... What is your purpose? How do you want to use it?

Comment: @N00b Wasn't it your variable name? You'd better use `oldtoday[0]`... (If you do not need to exactly use the name 'oldtoday00.')

Comment: yeah it is but this textview is causing problems if i declare int array or string array it work if i do like u said

Comment: oldtoday00 is my textview id

Comment: @N00b Please add more of your code and explanation. @_@ I cannot figure out what you want to do...

Comment: Ah, so you want to load `TextView`s from a layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
@IdRes int[] textViewIds = {R.id.firstTestView, R.id.secondTextView, ...};
TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[textViewIds.length];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (int i = 0; i < textViewIds.length; i++) {
        textViewArray[i] = (TextView) findViewById(textViewIds[i]);
    }
}
```

The idea is to store view ids into an array and to inflate them in onCreate()